# How do I fix unittest AssertionError 400 != 302

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, http-post, python-unittest

Writing some unittests to test POST request functions using Flask/Python. I cannot get the test to give me status 302 in the first part of the test. AssertionError: 400 != 302

```
def test_edited_user(self):
        with app.test_client() as client:

            # test post/edit data was sent and redirected
            data = {'first_name': self.user_fn, 'last_name': self.user_ln}
            res = client.post(f'/users/{self.user_id}/edit', data=data)
            self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 302)

            # test redirect to /users
            res = client.get('/users')
            html = res.get_data(as_text=True)

            self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
            self.assertIn('has been updated', html)
```

Here is the original route/function for reference:

```
@app.route('/users/<int:user_id>/edit', methods=['POST'])
def edited_user(user_id):
    """sends form data to edit user and database"""
    first_name = request.form['first_name']
    last_name = request.form['last_name']
    
    user = User.query.session.get(User, user_id)
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    
    db.session.commit()

    flash(f'User has been updated to {first_name} {last_name}!')
    return redirect('/users')
```

I have tried hard-coding data = {'first_name': 'TestFirst', 'last_name': 'TestLast' }
I have tried setting content_type = 'application/json' but I received a JSON is not defined error. I don't think it is a JSON error as the form data is submitted through text inputs through an html form (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: You posted the view function for `/users/new`, but your test function is calling `/users/user_id/edit` ...

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, I had copy/pasted the wrong view function. Showing the correct view function now.